# How to turn off monitor on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, ssh, display

I'm running Ubuntu Server on an old iMac. The server monitor does not shut off after boot, but that only started happening after a recent update. Until now, `setterm -blank 10` in my `~/.bashrc` did the trick (and, yes, I did try `--blank` instead of `-blank`, even though the latter has been working for months). But now, it stays on constantly.

I've tried the following (via ssh):

`sudo vbetool dpms off`

> mmap /dev/zero: Operation not permitted 
> Failed to initialise LRMI (Linux Real-Mode Interface).

I edited /etc/sudoers by granting `myuname ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/vbetool`, but to no effect.

`sudo xset dpms force off`

> xset:  unable to open display ""

`xrandr --query`

> Can't open display.

The `$DISPLAY` environment variable is not set.

Neither `ps aux | grep "X "` nor `ps aux | grep -i display` produce any output to help identify display IDs.

And that's the depth of my toolbox, I'm afraid. Any help to shut off my monitor would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `xset -display :0 dpms force off` works for me (without `sudo`).

Comment: Thanks @Jos. I still get an error with your suggestion: 'xset:  unable to open display ":0"'

Comment: What is the output of `ls /tmp/.X11-unix/`? Every X display should correspond to an entry there.

Comment: Literally nothing. Here it is. `total 8.0K
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4.0K Jul 12 20:59 .
drwxrwxrwt 16 root root 4.0K Jul 12 21:31 ..`

Comment: Then you don't have an X server running. Which is normal for a Ubuntu Server. `vbetool dpms off` still seems to be the way to go.

Comment: I get the same error with `vbetool dpms off` (without sudo) as I reported above. It's not clear to me what "Failed to initialise LRMI (Linux Real-Mode Interface)" means.

Comment: See `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vbetool/+bug/1875240` where a solution  for this error was found: editing `grub` by adding `iomem=relaxed`, and rebooting.

Comment: I tried both editing grub by adding `iomem=relaxed` (updating grub, and rebooting), as well as using the `mount -o remount,exec /dev` which was recorded as a solution on that bug report. Both yielded the same LRMI initialization error when running the vbetool.

Comment: Try adding `consoleblank=60` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` in the `/etc/default/grub` file, then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot the system.  1 minute (60 seconds) after boot, the monitor should turn off.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance. This seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @chaoborid Changed my comment into an answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `consoleblank=60` or any mount of seconds that you want to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line in the `/etc/default/grub` file.  Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot the system.

After your choice of seconds added to `consoleblank` the monitor should turn off after booting the system up.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a good trick. On my iMac screen goes off correctly after boot. However if I try to type some commands, next time screen will go to a white screen. Why is it?

Comment: @PouJa `consoleblank=` whould be used on a server and not a desktop.  If you are running a server on your iMac and use this, it may be conflicting with the local video driver that might have been installed.  Usually though, servers are meant to be headless and it without actual keyboard interaction.  If this is a desktop system with a full GUI, I would recommend not to use this, but to use the screensaver software instead with the screen blanking.

Comment: It is a desktop computer but with headless ubuntu server installed on it. I use it as a small home server and in the night it makes my room glow. I don't know how to make the screen go off automatically after some seconds of idling and come back on just after I press a button.

Comment: @PouJa You might want to look more into the Power saving modes then https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower.  The `consoleblank=` command line option I don't think powers the monitor off, as I know that when the monitor I have hooked up to my server will still glow all the time.  So I just power mine all the way off and I don't touch my server unless I absolutely have to like in a failure or in a OS update on it when it could go offline from my remote control.