# USB plug in; no one is there to see it; why does it not mount?

Tags: 20.04, usb, mount, lock-screen

Does anyone have any understanding why screen blanking (not screen locking, that sort of makes sense) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS prevents it from mounting a USB key that is plugged in? As far as I can tell, the USB/SD/kernel side of this all runs, but then the actually "mount this as a filesystem" piece doesn't.

I'm actively using the machine over an SSH connection, but the keyboard and mouse aren't convenient to keep touching/wiggling to keep the screen lit up. And I don't understand why this should matter?

On the plus side it makes for a nice haiku-style poem.

Comment: Is the screen actually blanking?  Or is the system going into a standby lower power mode?  Standby with minimal a minimal system running is very low powered so the USB may not have enough power to operate.  I don't know what your remote system is that you are connecting to over SSH, like a server or something, but you might want to disable all power saving features on it.  And if it is a server, you can blank only the screen after it boots up https://askubuntu.com/a/1351633/231142  Really though, we need more details about your setup to give you better answer(s) that will help.  Thank you!

Comment: Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using?  20.04 LTS?  20.10?  Ubuntu Core 20?

Comment: @Terrance - as per the tag 20.04. I have edited the question to state 20.04 LTS. I don't thing it's going into a low power mode as it is immediately responsive and continues to supply SSH connections throughout.
I was able to resolve the issue by telling it "blank screen never" - I had remembered that some of the settings were administratively locked out, but apparently not that one.

Comment: Sorry about missing the 20.04 as we have had lots of questions here where people tag that but are using something completely different.  Usually it is best to state it in your question.  As far as the blank screen never is concerned, blanking the screen is part of power saving features.  It could have also been locking the screen thus causing locking of the USB ports.  Anyways, I am glad that you got it working.  Feel free to write up your own answer about solving it.