# How to turn off laptop display on Ubuntu Server 22.04?

Tags: server, display, laptop, samsung

I use the laptop as a server with remote access. I tried installing xandr but it doesn't work.

Laptop model: Samsung NP305V5A-A05DX

Problem solved. This instruction helped: [How to turn off monitor on Ubuntu Server](https://askubuntu.com/q/1351533/32664)

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help in troubleshooting your issue, please include the make/model of your laptop, as there may be a way to disable your specific display device. Also, are you hoping to disable the display remotely, or via keypress/key combination? Thanks

Comment: @richbl Oh, okay. Laptop model is Samsung NP305V5A-A05DX

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but here's one approach previously discussed: https://askubuntu.com/q/1351533/32664

Comment: @richbl it should be like this? https://imgur.com/zfHWN7I
Yeah, it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Sentyreon, in order to correctly close out this question, please accept the answer I've created from my original comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to resolving your issue (called "screenblanking") would be to use the `consoleblank` kernel option, which blanks the device's display after some configured period of time. [There's a good prior discussion of this here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351533/how-to-turn-off-monitor-on-ubuntu-server).